# Performance of programs with low priority on otherwise idle computer

Tags: windows, performance, scheduler, windows-task-scheduler

Is there a performance difference between running a single program with a lowered scheduling priority than default on an otherwise idle windows computer?

Does the scheduler run more often for lower prioritized tasks, or something like that, that causes some notable performance loss?

Comment: In principle no, if the computer is idle. However, if you try to measure the execution time, you will most likely see a longer burn in, i.e. it takes a while before the process gets full attention. This is also the case, if you change your performance settings. In general, it is good practice to measure performance using a thread, which was busy just before the tasks you want to measure... I believe someone can provide a better answer and it is probably already answered elsewhere